# Building an simple ecommerce site with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I read the Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1. The author used a scaffold to generate products. In my product page (`show.html.erb`), I'm able to purchase an item. If I wanted to add sizes to my product, how would I go about that? Do I add a size column in my product table?

In my show.html.erb file, I have

```
<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

This allows me to send the product id to the controller. I understand that the button is a form. However, the `show.html.erb` page is not a form. How could I pass additional params such as the size of the product to the `line_items_path`?

Comment: Size should be a column of the products table and not line items. Each size should be a unique product. The key reason here is that you should be able to keep a stock of each size.

Comment: This is also two separate questions masquerading as one. The larger design question about how to model product sizes is a bit too broad. The second question is about how to add additional attributes to `button_to` is very likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have try:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: @product, size: @product.size), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: I did. I added the following code: <%= select_tag(:size, options_for_select([['Extra-large', 'Extra-large'], ['Large', 'Large']]))%> for the sizes. Should I add the sizes in the database? I have tried that, but then how do I get them to drop down and add value to each size?

Comment: I have viewed your source code, is a problem that you have the default sizes you store in the model and in show product you want to scroll all size option in a form and submit with product id when you create one?

Comment: I tried a different method, so that's why I had the default sizes in the model, but I'm not using them throughout the application.

Comment: why not you use enum for size instead of using the constant? Use can iterate it in views instead of hard-coding, instead of using submit button you can using form_tag to pass size params in select_box when submit form.